# CORS issue with Express Router end points

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a react app that is making a REST to a an express node server.

The express router defines a bunch of rest endpoints.

When I hit the endpoints in the express router using postman, it works fine.

When I hit the endpoint with me react app, it doesn't. I'm seeing 400 error when my react app makes the call using axios.

This is what my index.js looks like:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// server.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
// app.options("*", cors());

const UserModel = require("./models/User");

mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb"
  )
  .then(() => console.log("SUCESSFULLY connected to MongoDB!"))
  .catch((error) => console.log(`FAILED tot connect to MongoDB: ${error}`));

require("./auth/localStrategyAuth");

const authRoutes = require("./routes/authRoutes");
app.use("/v1", authRoutes);

// app.post("/", (req, res) => {
//   res.send("Hello World!");
// });
// app.post("/v1/signup", (req, res) => {
//   console.log("lol");
// });

// app.use(express.json());
const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`ui-rest listening on port localhost:${PORT}`)
);
```

user.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
module.exports = UserModel;
```

authRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const JWTstrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
//We use this to extract the JWT sent by the user
const ExtractJWT = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;

const router = express.Router();

// When the user sends a post request to this route, passport authenticates the user based on the
// middleware created previously
router.post(
  "/signup",
  passport.authenticate("signup", { session: false }),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({
      message: "Signup successful",
      user: req.user,
    });
  }

module.exports = router;
```

localStrategyAuth.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
const localStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const UserModel = require("../models/User");

//Create a passport middleware to handle user registration
passport.use(
  "signup",
  new localStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
    },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        // Save the information provided by the user to the the database
        const user = await UserModel.create({ email, password });
        // Send the user information to the next middleware
        return done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {
        done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

This is what my express router looks like:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post(
  "/signup",
  passport.authenticate("signup", { session: false }),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({
      message: "Signup successful",
      user: req.user,
    });
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

What am I missing? I've set up CORS in the index.js file. I just can't see where I'm going wrong. Why cant my react app hit the express router endpoints.

If I have a normal express endpoint, then my react app is able to hit those endpoints. For example, the endpoint below works fine when my react app hits it.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`listening on port localhost:${PORT}`)

app.post("/someSignup", (req, res) => {
   console.log("signup");
 });
```

I've also tried things like with no luck:

```
const authRoutes = require("./routes/authRoutes");
authRoutes.use(cors());
```

Here is what my react code looks like when it submits the rest call:

```
  // axios setup
axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
  // headers: {
  //   "Content-Type": "application/json",
  // },
});

  // Handle submit
  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const newUserData = {
      // firstName: this.state.firstName,
      // lastName: this.state.lastName,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    };
    const result = await axios.post("/v1/signup", newUserData);
    console.log(result);
  };
```

Here is a screenshot of headers tab on chrome console
[image]

Here is a screenshot of response tab on chrome console
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the request
[image]

Comment: 400  means bad request. What displays on the response tab in the screenshot?

Comment: That the response I'm getting from the express node server when my react app makes rest call to it.

Comment: What does it display? Can you add to the question. Also can yo add the react code where you call this api?

Comment: @SuleymanSah updated description with react code that makes the rest call. What do you mean by `what does it display`

Comment: Show response tab, right to the headers tab.

Comment: @SuleymanSah Updated description with images of request, headers and response tab.

Comment: The email you send is not a valid email, so you get 400 bad request.

Comment: I've tried with a valid email and its the same issue. I get a bad request. The email shouldn't make a difference for the time being. I'm just trying to get an endpoint hit by the react app.

Comment: Which middlewares do you use? Can you add all code in your main file?

Comment: Updated with full code from index.js

Comment: You're getting a 400 Bad Request error. What makes you think this has anything to do with CORS?

Comment: "When I hit the endpoints in the express router using postman, it works fine" — So compare the request headers sent by the browser with the ones sent by Postman. Edit the ones in Postman to match, one by one until you trigger the 400 error. Then you'll know what the problem is.

Comment: Can you also add full authRoutes.js and ./auth/localStrategyAuth code?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Added `authRoutes` and `localStrategyAuth`

Comment: Also can you wrap your api call in a try catch, and what displays in browser console?
`try {
  const result = await axios.post("/v1/signup", newUserData);
  console.log(result.data);
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Error: ", err.response.data);
}`  send valid email, and password.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I get this in the console `Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)`

Comment: Can you add your mongoose User model code?

Comment: Updated with mongoose usermodel

Comment: What is this line? `module.exports = UserModel;` where does UserModel comes? Normally it should be like this: `module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);`

Comment: I copied and pasted incorrectly. Updated the model

Comment: You have unique option in email, I think that's the problem. Can you try with a valid and unused email like   test1@gmail.com ?

Comment: I've tried with many different emails and the same issue. That doesn't help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211001/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-breaktop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

400 means bad request, your problem isn't about with cors.
You didn't setup your api to handle JSON data which react sends, so it can't read your request.body and gives 400-Bad Request.

So you need to add this line:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Also in the current versions of express, body parser isn't required , it comes with express. So you can use it like this:

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

The reason it worked with postman is that you sent the data in x-www-form-urlencoded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use check my code for cors error.

```
const express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express();

// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());
// Logger Middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));
// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "uri";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
client.connect(err => {
  console.log('MongoDB Connected...')
  const collection = client.db("dbname").collection("collectionname");

  app.post('/name', (req, res) => {
    collection. insertOne({ name: req.body.name })
    res.send("data added")
  });

});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: enable const cors = require("cors"); for the bug

Comment: the issue is with express router endpoints. Normal express endpoints works fine

Answer (score -1):

You need to register the cors middleware into express app.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port localhost:${PORT}`)
```

Comment: I've tried that with no luck. I'm not sure what I'm missing. The issue is with the express router endpoints. I'm not able to hit the express router exports. I have added an example in the description.

Comment: Try setting this `"proxy": "http://localhost: 5000"` in react `package.json` file

Comment: I've also tried that in my react app. That didn't help. I've attached screenshot with the 400 error